# Building Caffe on Windows without Python for C++ / OpenCV usage

Tags: c++, build, cmake, caffe

I'd like to build Caffe on my windows machine using VS2019. Executing CMake, I get the error:

> Building without python. Prebuilt dependencies will default to Python 2.7
>   CMake Error at cmake/WindowsDownloadPrebuiltDependencies.cmake:40 (message):
>     Could not find url for MSVC version = 1916 and Python version = ..
>   Call Stack (most recent call first):
>     CMakeLists.txt:77 (include)

I read about the error in a google research and the answer is always 
`"Set the python directory"`

I don't have python installed on my computer and I also wouldn't like to as I just want caffe to use in C++ and/or OpenCV.

I also set the cmake parameter `BUILD_python = false`and `BUILD_python_layer = false`

[image]

Can somebody guide me, how to come arround that?

Thank you.

Maybe it's helpful - here is "Line 40 from the `WindowsCreateLinkHeader.cmake`File:

```
get_filename_component(MSVC_VC_DIR [HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\\SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\VisualStudio\\${MSVC_PRODUCT_VERSION_${MSVC_VERSION}}\\Setup\\VC;ProductDir] REALPATH CACHE)
```

Answer (score 0):

okey, here goes nothing :)

If you take a look at [this](https://github.com/BVLC/caffe/blob/windows/cmake/WindowsDownloadPrebuiltDependencies.cmake) file(WindowsDownloadPrebuiltDependencies.cmake) you will find that DEPENDENCIES_NAME_* and DEPENDENCIES_URL_* do not contain MSCV version 1916, only 1900 and 1800. This is what the error is actually saying to you.

One fix would be to change all 1900_27 to 1916_27 and pray to your favorite god that it is still compatible.
27 is by the way Python version 2.7 which the error states to be the default.

Have not tried this myself so it is kinda unsure if it really would work but hey, maybe one step closer for you :)

Answer (score 0):

With Visual Studio 2015 and Python3.6:
I was able to run `scripts\build_win.cmd` with a small change in `WindowsDownloadPrebuiltDependencies.cmake` file, by converting all the set(`DEPENDENCIES_URL_1900_27 ....` to `set(DEPENDENCIES_URL_1900_36......`